# Configuration OpenCv in Qt in windows

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator

I'm working in a artificial vision project, that requires a GUI for user interaction.

After looking for some posibles solutions, I decided to program with Qt.

I follow some tutorials I found, but at the end I have always the same issue: if I type some opencv code, the program crashed after it starts.

I'm working with opencv 2.4.10 and Qt 5.3.2 with Visual Studio compiler (MSCV 2010 for 32bit).

For learning purpose I'm trying to deploy the following project:

- opencvButton.pro:

  ```
  QT       += core gui

  greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

  TARGET = opencvButton
  TEMPLATE = app
  INCLUDEPATH += C:\\opencv\\build\\include
  LIBS += -LC:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib \
       -lopencv_calib3d2410d \
       -lopencv_contrib2410d \
       -lopencv_core2410d \
       -lopencv_features2d2410d \
       -lopencv_flann2410d \
       -lopencv_gpu2410d \
       -lopencv_highgui2410d \
       -lopencv_imgproc2410d \
       -lopencv_legacy2410d \
       -lopencv_ml2410d \
       -lopencv_nonfree2410d \
       -lopencv_objdetect2410d \
       -lopencv_ocl2410d \
       -lopencv_photo2410d \
       -lopencv_stitching2410d \
       -lopencv_superres2410d \
       -lopencv_ts2410d \
       -lopencv_video2410d \
       -lopencv_videostab2410d


  SOURCES += main.cpp\
      mainwindow.cpp

  HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

  FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
  ```
- mainwindow.h:

  ```
  #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
  #define MAINWINDOW_H

  #include <QMainWindow>
  #include <QPushButton>
  #include <QMessageBox>
  #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

  namespace Ui {
       class MainWindow;
  }

  class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
  {
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
      private slots:
      void handleButton();
  private:
      QPushButton *m_button;
  };

  #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
  ```
- main.cpp:

  ```
  #include "mainwindow.h"

  #include <QApplication>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QApplication app(argc, argv);

      MainWindow mainWindow;
      mainWindow.showMaximized();
      return app.exec();
  }
  ```
- And finally, mainwindow.cpp:
       #include "mainwindow.h"

  ```
   #include <QCoreApplication>

   using namespace cv;

   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
       : QMainWindow(parent)
  {
       // Create the button, make "this" the parent
       m_button = new QPushButton("Display image", this);
       // set size and location of the button
       m_button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100, 100), QSize(200, 50)));

       // Connect button signal to appropriate slot
       connect(m_button, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (handleButton()));
  }

   void MainWindow::handleButton()
  {
      // Define image path
      String imaloc = "C:\\Users\\Virtualmech\\Desktop\\ipRedCable.png";
      // Mat instance declaration image.
      Mat image;
      // Load imaloc image in Mat instance.
      image = imread(imaloc);
      if(image.empty()){
           QMessageBox::about(this, "Error", "Cannot load image");
      }else{
          // Declare name of window
          namedWindow("Display image");
          // Show image
          imshow("Display image", image);
          // Wait for user interaction
          waitKey(0);
          // Close and destroy window
          destroyAllWindows();
      }
  }
  ```

This project consists in a single button, and when you click it, the program should show an image in the path imaloc.

The application output I get is:

> Starting C:\Users\Virtualmech\Documents\opencvButton\debug\opencvButton.exe...
>
> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>
> C:\Users\Virtualmech\Documents\opencvButton\debug\opencvButton.exe crashed

And this without even starts.

If I comment opencv related code in mainwindow.cpp, the program runs perfectly.

Now, if I just only declare (without defining) a **Mat** instance, the application quits off running, and shows again the same output.

I think it must be a configuration issue, but I can't find it.

Could anyone give any clue?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to put the necessary dlls next to the executable you are trying to run, in the debug folder in your case.

To find out which dlls you are missing, try to run the program directly instead of doing it through Qt Creator's interface.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I thought that by typing in **.pro** file lines of **INCLUDEPATH** (for .h) and **LIBS** (for .lib) was enough. Now I understand that I have to link **.dlls** as well. I'm going to try to include this files and post feedback.

Comment: Thanks so much. You was absolutly right. I just copy into my project folder **.dll** files related to my **.lib** files and the project runs perfectly :))